# Routing not working in React Js Application

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I just start building a website using react.js but when I tried to route the application using `react-router-dom` it doesn't work. It won't show any error and it will display blank page in `localhost:3000`.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Card from './components/Card/Card';
import CardData from './components/Card/CardData';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Pages/Home/Home';
import Contact from './components/Pages/Contact/Contact';
import Products from './components/Pages/Products/Products';
import About from './components/Pages/About/About';

const cards = CardData.map(item => {
    return (
        <Card
            key={item.id}
            item={item}
        />
    )
})

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Navbar />
                <Route path='/'>
                    <Home />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/products'>
                    <Products />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/contact'>
                    <Contact />
                </Route>
                <Route path='/about'>
                    <About />
                </Route>
                <section className="cards-list">
                   {cards}
                </section>
                <Footer />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

As mentioned above, it should be able to navigate throughout pages but when I tried the `localhost:3000` it will display a blank page. It won't display anything or any errors.

Comment: Missing also is the `Routes` component that must directly wrap all `Route` components.

Comment: still, the same

Comment: You fixed *both* the `Routes` and `Route` component issues? *What* exactly is still the same? Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: okay i have code in codesandbox and this one is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-dust-h5xo6d?file=/src/index.js

Comment: In the sandbox the `Route` components are still incorrectly used. The only children of a `Route` component are other nested `Route` components. Use the `element` prop for routed content.